# shelljs "not found" error

Tags: node.js, shell, shelljs

I have below .sh file

```
// ping.sh
01: port="$1"
02: echo "pinging http://localhost:$port/ping"
03: 
04: retry=0
05: while
06:     sleep 1
07:     api_response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null "http://localhost:$port/ping")
08:     echo "resp $api_response"
09:     (( "$api_response" != "200" && ++retry < 100 ))
10: do :; done
```

When I run it directly with `./ping.sh 8080`, it works fine. However, when I run it with shelljs it fails with below error.

```
// ping.js
require('shelljs').exec("./ping.sh 8080", {async:true});

$ node ping.js 
pinging http://localhost:8080/ping
resp 000 ./ping.sh: 9: ./ping.sh: 000: not found
```

Comment: it looks like the (( )) syntax is not supported in shelljs, i think this only works in bash

Comment: I converted it to a for loop but now I get same error in this line `if [ "$api_response" == "200" ]; then`. I am afraid I will switch to `child_process` instead of `shelljs`

Comment: why not a library like this? https://github.com/danielzzz/node-ping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work , simply add `#!/bin/bash` to `ping.sh`

---

### Working proof-of-concept :

> ## ping.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
port="$1"
echo "pinging http://localhost:$port/ping"

retry=0
while
 sleep 1
 api_response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null "http://localhost:$port/ping")
 echo "resp $api_response"
 (( "$api_response" != "200" && ++retry < 100 ))
do :; done
```

> ## ping.js

```
require('shelljs').exec("./ping.sh 8080", {async:true});
```

> ## terminal output :

```
node ping.js
pinging http://localhost:8080/ping
resp 000
resp 000
```